# Why Docker doesn't recognize its network?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to run the simplest docker container and open psql in one command. Looking at [official doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), I tried:

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h some-postgres -U postgres
```

getting `docker: Error response from daemon: network some-network not found.`

after running `docker network create some-network` and retrying the exact same command, I got

```
psql: error: could not translate host name "some-postgres" to address: Name or service not known
```

Using `-h localhost` instead resulted in `psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused`. I also tried adding `-p 5432:5432` but got the same result.

What I thought:

1. `docker run -it --rm`: start a ephemeral container keeping its shell exposed into my current shell
2. `--network some-network postgres` defines what network it will use and the image name used
3. `psql -h some-postgres -U postgres` is the command run against the container, in this case, starting a psql client defining host and user

What is happening differently from what I thought?

**EDIT**

I successfully ran these 2 appart:

1. `docker run -it --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -p 5432:5432 postgres` started a new postgres container and 'locked' my terminal into postgres logs, but I wasn't able to run anything
2. `psql -h localhost -U postgres` successfully connected on the previous container. Since I'm not inside the container env, I had to map port and use `localhost`

Why running these 2 combined doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres -> psql -h some-postgres -U postgres <-
```

you are overriding the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) from the [docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/38841304ddd06dd3b39cc080b2c8fce5a5be8e52/13/Dockerfile#L187) and the postgres server is not run.

With the official postgres image you can't start the postgres server container and run the psql at the same time from the same container.

You do have a couple of options here:

1. Start postgres server in one container and psql command in another

```sh
# create a bridge network
docker network create postgres_net
# start the server in the background
docker run --rm -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name postgres --network postgres_net postgres
# override entrypoint and run psql command
docker run --rm -it -e PGPASSWORD=password --network postgres_net postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

2. Start postgres container, access container shell and run psql from there

```sh
# start the server in the background
docker run --rm -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name postgres --network postgres_net postgres
# access bash shell from postgres container and run psql inside
docker exec -it postgres bash
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run this command...

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

You are replacing the default behavior of the image (start up a `postgres` server) by running the `psql` command instead. This means you're not starting Postgres, so `psql` has nothing to which it can connect.